# jQuery Sorting shows wrong sorting order

Tags: jquery, sorting

I am working on a table to sort it with jquery. But the Problem is, the table get sorted with wrong order.

```
Like: 1, 10, 100, 101.... etc
```

it should show `Like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...`

Please advise me what to do.

My Codes are as following.

HTML Codes

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label style="width:100%;background-color:#efebeb;" for="fileupload" class="custom-file-upload"><i class="fa fdicon fa-folder-open"></i> Select Folder</label>
                        <input id="fileupload" type="file" webkitdirectory directory multiple/>
                    </div>
                </div>
<div class="col-md-12">
            
<table id="RecTable" class="table table-bordered RecordsTable" style="display:none;">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th style="text-align:center;" onclick="sort_age();">ACT</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Performer</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Section</th>


</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="GetRecords">
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="hidden" id="age_order" value="asc">        
</div>
```

Here are my JavaScript codes.

```
$("#fileupload").change(function(){
$(".custom-file-upload").html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Folder Selected');
var fileList = $('#fileupload').prop("files");
$('#uploadsts').html('');
$('#RecTable').show();
  var i;
    for(i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
        var FileName = fileList[i].name;
        var ACT = FileName.split(' - ')[0];
        var Performer = FileName.split(' - ')[2];
        var Section = FileName.split(' - ')[3];
        var Sec = Section.split('.')[0];
        //var ext = FileName.split('.')[1];
        var ext = FileName.substr( (FileName.lastIndexOf('.') +1) ).toLowerCase();
        var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i]);
        $('#GetRecords').show();
        $('#GetRecords').append('<tr id="Row'+ACT+'" class="RecRow"><td style="text-align:center;"><a class="ACTlink text-primary" style="cursor:pointer;" data-rel="'+ACT+'">'+ACT+'</a></td><td>'+Performer+'</td><td>'+Sec+'</td></tr>');
        if(ext == 'pdf'){
            $('#FolderFiles').append('<span class="imgbox" style="display:none;" id="'+ACT+'"><embed src="'+tmppath+'" width="100%" style="height: 100%;" type="application/pdf"></span>');
        }else{
        $('#FolderFiles').append('<span class="imgbox" style="display:none;" rel="'+ext+'" id="'+ACT+'"><img data-rel="'+ACT+'" class="rotate" src="images/rotate.png"><img class="img'+ACT+'" style="max-width:100%;"  src="'+tmppath+'"></span>');
        }
     }
});

//Sorting
function sort_age() 
{
 var table=$('#RecTable');
 var tbody =$('#GetRecords');

 tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a, b) 
 {
  if($('#age_order').val()=='asc') 
  {
   return $('td:first', a).text().localeCompare($('td:first', b).text());
  }
  else 
  {
   return $('td:first', b).text().localeCompare($('td:first', a).text());
  }
        
 }).appendTo(tbody);
    
 var sort_order=$('#age_order').val();
 if(sort_order=="asc")
 {
  document.getElementById("age_order").value="desc";
 }
 if(sort_order=="desc")
 {
  document.getElementById("age_order").value="asc";
 }
}
```

When I click on `ACT` it changes sorting but it shows wrong sorting.. `ACT` is `Numeric or Alphanumeric`
Basically this code is used to show all the files `onselect`. It will show all files in table when the user will just select the directory. Everything works perfect, Just sorting is the issue.

Kindly point out my mistake which I have made here.

Comment: propably you can use 'string.padStart()' to add leading zeros before comparing the strings:  https://www.techonthenet.com/js/string_padstart.php

Comment: *ACT is numeric or alphanumeric* - then how should it be sorted?    "1" < "2" which is alpha (so "100" is less than "2").  I suggest converting both to numbers, then if they're the same value (0) using text sort (on the original values, not converted ofc)

Comment: I am sorry I could not understand both of you. 
Can you please give me an example. how to do that. According to my code.